# Date selector PhP/JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I looked for answers, but I am a newbie to PhP/JQuery so the answers I found confused me further.

I have a wordpress website that contains a form with a date selector field I am trying to determine when the user selects a new date and save that date to a variable to be used somwhere else

On change doesn't work cause of the lack of focus etc...

I tried select, and that didn't do anything

In the process of trying to figur eout what I am doing wrong, I simplified the code where once it is selected it gives me a message box! the code is below:
Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
$JScript ="<script>
jQuery('#wdform_2_element13').on('select',function() 
        {
            alert('Here');

        }
</script>"
```

Comment: with the code provided SO people can only guess.. Please provide all relevant code to the OP

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the process when your saving all your data from the form, and call a new function to save or do whatever you want to that variable.

You can do that by pointing your form submissions to a specific file in the `wp-admin` directory called `admin-post.php`

Take a look to this tutorial and I'm sure you will learn some basic knowledge about WP code and also the answer to your question:

https://www.sitepoint.com/handling-post-requests-the-wordpress-way/

Comment: Thanks I will check it out!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the reason is cause the field was a date picker that was already defined through the form maker i was using. So what I did was create a date picker using Jquery, then use the "onSelect:function" and that was it

Thanks for the help